# Was variable x ever true?

Tags: javascript, variables

In Javascript, is there a good way to check if a variable was **ever** a true, (or any value), in the entire session? The best way I can think of right now is to perform a regular check like this, recording the truthiness in another variable:

```
if (variable){
  variablewasevertrue = true;
}
```

Then when I want to know if the original `variable` was ever true, I check if the new `variablewasevertrue` is `true` or `undefined`. There's nothing more graceful like `if (variable was ever true){` is there? That doesn't seem very Javascript-y.

Comment: What overall problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps there is a better way of going about it.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Chances are there that whatever causes the variable to change may provide you with some ability to reach your goal.

Comment: It's a global variable inside an object. It gets nullified after the object goes through a particular process once but its value also determines if something else happens repeatedly. I guess I'll just roll with two variables. Seemed kind of like brute force coding but maybe not.

Comment: Mike did you really edit my post with a word invented by Stephen Colbert?

Comment: @Artur, yes.  `if (variable)` does not establish that `variable` is `true` since that test passes when `variable` is `1`, `[]`, and many other values.   To check for that you need `if (variable === true)`.

Comment: Fair enough, but "truthiness"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there is no `if (variable was ever true)` facility in the language.  Variables store values, not history.

Intercepting values as they're assigned and checking is the only way to do it.  If the variable is really a property (e.g. a global variable is a property of the global object) you can intercept changes easily using [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

So to have a history keeping global variable you could do

```
var hasEverBeenTruthy = false;
(function () {
  var value;
  Object.defineProperty(window, "myGlobal", {
    "get": function () { return value; },
    "set": function (newval) {
      if (newval) { hasEverBeenTruthy = true; }
      value = newval;
    }
  });
})();
```

This will work on modern browsers, and there are `__defineSetter__` variants on many older browsers.

Comment: Thanks this is actually pretty powerful as a variable-setting bottleneck.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only work for variables in the window namespace.  If you want it to work within a function you'll need to change the definition to be within that functions namespace (which is hard with anonymous functions)

Comment: @Mike Trpcic, I thought I had made that clear with "If the variable is really a property (e.g. a global variable is a property of the global object)..."

Comment: @MikeSamuel might want to leave a mention to ES6 proxies.

Answer (score 7):

Variables store value, not a history of a memory location.  If you want to do something like this, I would suggest you use an Object of some sort:

```
var x = {
    value: false,
    history: [],
    set: function(val){
        history.push(this.value);
        this.value = val;
    },
    wasEver: function(val){
        return this.history.indexOf(val) >= 0;
    }
};
```

Then you can use the object like so:

```
x.set(false);
x.value; //returns false

x.set(true);
x.value; //returns true

x.wasEver(true); // returns true
x.wasEver(false); //returns true
x.wasEver("hello"); //returns false
```

This gives each object it's own history (as in, it can check multiple values, not just one - as with the getter/setter stuff mentioned in other answers), and is guaranteed to work in any scope, as all functionality is contained within the defined object.

Comment: Agreed, very nice use of an array

Comment: Am I wrong or would lines 5 and 6 in the first part of your code have to be switched?

Comment: @Artur:  It depends on what you want.  In the current code, the value only goes into the history array AFTER it has been changed (that is, the "current value" of the object is NOT in the history array).  If you want the current value in the history array, just swap those two lines.

Answer (score 5):

No, except that you could use a `getter` and `setter` like this, which delegates the setting of a variable so that you can check whether it is to set at one time:

```
var value,
    wasevertrue = false;

window.__defineSetter__('test', function(v) {
    value = v;
    wasevertrue = wasevertrue || (v === true);
});

window.__defineGetter__('test', function() {
    return value;
});
```

Now,

```
test = false; // wasevertrue === false
test = true;  // wasevertrue === true
test = false; // wasevertrue === true
```

Better yet would be putting this in a closure because you can now just set `value = true` as a workaround to the setter.

Comment: You should note that the defineSetter methods aren't standard and won't be as cross-platform as some other solutions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineSetter

Answer (score 1):

no - there is no state tracking on variables. it is only whatever its current value is. beyond that its your own custom implementation using property-like methods for state tracking.

Answer (score 1):

Have another variable called "wasevertrue = false." Anywhere you set "variable" immediately follow it with a check that sees if variable == true. If it is, set wasevertrue = true.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a single scalar variable to track history, but you could use an array. It's not ideal, but it's an alternative:

```
function setVar(arr, value) {
    arr.unshift(value);
    return arr;
}

function getVar(arr) {
    return arr[0];
}

function checkHist(arr, histValue) {
    var ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < arr.length; ii++) {
        if (arr[ii] === histValue) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var myVar = [];
myVar = setVar(myVar, true);
myVar = setVar(myVar, false);

alert(checkHist(myVar, true)); // alerts "true"
```

Comment: A list of all settings, I see. Interesting idea